# Java - implementing another class and modifying the method

Tags: java

i have done this so far, but having difficulty with part b. It is a mock exam paper and not sure on the rest of part b.

Q)
Sum up the elements of a sequence given by `s.valAtIndex(i)`.
s is of type Seq.
Seq is an interface that has a method `valAtIndex (integer parameter and double result)`.

(a) write the interface Seq.

(b) write a class Geometric, implementing Seq. so that each instance s represents a geometric series as follows 
`s.valAtIndex(0), s.valAtIndex(0)`...
such that the ith element `s.valAtIndex(i)` is equal to the ith power of the base b i.e. b^i. (recall that b^0=1)

(a)

```
public interface Seq{

public double valAtIndex(int i);
}
```

(b)

```
public Geometric implements Seq{

Seq s;
private double b;

public Geometric(double a){

s = new Geometric(a);
this.b=a;
}

@Override
public double valAtIndex(int i){

return 0;//not sure how to do this method

}
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of `Geometric` inside your constructor. That's what the constructor is doing.

Comment: @Dancrumb That would be an infinite recursive loop, causing a stackoverflow exception. Also, it would be nice if this were labeled better... a->r, i->n.

valAtIndex is pretty easy, just use the formula: u0*r^(n-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
@Override
public double valAtIndex(int i) {
    return Math.pow(b, i);
}
```

?

EDIT: Also, as mentioned in other answers, remove `Seq s;` and the line regarding it in the constructor. What you should have at the end is:

```
public class Geometric implements Seq {
    private double b;

    public Geometric(double a) {
        this.b=a;
    }

    @Override
    public double valAtIndex(int i){
        return Math.pow(b, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding edits: I was a little confused for a bit regarding `@Override` tags for interface methods, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
@Override
public double valAtIndex(int i) {
    return Math.pow(b, i);
}
```

This would return b to the power of i.

However, your code would result in a stack overflow exception. You call a constructor for geometric inside the constructor. resulting in continious calling to the constructor and an exception.

You need to change your constructor to

```
public Geometric(double a) {
    this.b = a;
}
```

Also, you need to declare it as `class Geometric` instead of `public Geometric`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the class, was typing what I had wrote